# du: cannot access ‘/home/*’: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, automation, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to create an ansible playbook to check disk utilization of each users in the /home/ directory

```
---
- name: User Home Directory Stat
  hosts: linux7
  become: true


  vars:
    directory: /home/*

  tasks:
    - name: Check available user directory and disk utilization
      ansible.builtin.command: "sudo du -sh {{ directory }} "
      register: msg
    - debug:
        var: msg.stdout_lines
```

However, i get

```
FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["sudo", "du", "-sh", "/home/*"], "delta": "0:00:00.018716", "end": "2022-09-29 10:44:06.375725", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2022-09-29 10:44:06.357009", "stderr": "du: cannot access ‘/home/*’: No such file or directory", "stderr_lines": ["du: cannot access ‘/home/*’: No such file or directory"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Comment: Containers don't imply having a /home/, image containers are mostly "light" versions. No need of all this optional directories for humans.

Comment: "/home/*" will look for a literal path /home/* it will therefore look for a file called * in /home. /home/* (without quotes) There is therefore most probably an issue with the * Instead of using * and du -sh, use du -h --max-depth 1 and /home

Comment: From https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html, *"The command(s) will not be processed through the shell"*, so your wildcard is not processed.  Like @RamanSailopal said, it looks for a file named "*".  Use  ansible.builtin.shell to use wildcards.